# Hash Index on Pgsql table in EFCore

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

How can I specify the index type as "hash" for pgsql db in Efcore fluent api?

Eg:

> modelBuilder.Entity().HasIndex(u =>
> u.PId).IsUnique();

Is there any extension method specific to pgsql that accepts the index type? The default index type being created is 'btree'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [HasMethod](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlIndexBuilderExtensions.html#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_NpgsqlIndexBuilderExtensions_HasMethod_IConventionIndexBuilder_System_Nullable_System_String__System_Boolean_) like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity().HasIndex(u => u.PId).HasMethod("hash")
```

the method according to [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)

> method
>
> The name of the index method to be used. Choices are btree, hash, gist, spgist, gin, and brin. The default method is btree.